# Where can I find go-go bars in Bangkok?

Tags: nightlife, bangkok

I am going to go to Bangkok in 3 days, and will visit the go-go bar, but I have no idea on this, anybody has the information about go-go bar in Bangkok? Thx

Comment: There are Go-Go bars all over Bangkok.  You go in, you buy a drink, you watch the girls dance, you go home.

Comment: @Tom Prostitution can be found all over Bangkok; go-go bars, however, cannot.

Comment: @jpatokal - My comment was sarcastic anti-sex tourist ... watch then go home ... not go home with a girlfriend for the night.

Answer (score 7):

There are actually only three areas in Bangkok licensed for actual [go-go bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_go_bar), meaning scantily dressed girls of negotiable virtue dancing on stage:

1. [Patpong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patpong), the original, the most infamous, the seediest and the touristiest
2. [Nana Plaza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nana_Plaza), essentially a single building packed full of go-gos
3. [Soi Cowboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soi_Cowboy), a short lane packed full of more go-gos

There are also a few gay go-go areas, notably [Soi Pratuchai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soi_Pratuchai) quite close to Patpong.

See [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bangkok#Go-go_and_beer_bars) for a quick rundown of how these places work and how to behave yourself — and yes, it's perfectly OK to go just for a drink.