# Safety in Bangkok

Tags: safety, thailand, bangkok

I am going to BKK at the beginning of October and being a tourist and a photographer, I wouldn't renounce to take my camera with me (it's not a bullseye for thieves, but still...).
Do I need to stay away from areas in the city to avoid being robbed?
Can I enjoy any nightlife without being anxious about anything?
Are nightclubs trustworthy?
I actually have fun trying to talk with people and wouldn't want in any way sound or look rude to them, so I often decline with a smile if I am not interested in something, but is there any kind of scammers to absolutely avoid?

Comment: Welcome! You're relatively new, so I suggest checking out the [help], where you'll note subjective questions are generally off-topic, and you're expected to ask generally just one question per post.  Possibly you could edit this after reading it, as in its current state it's likely to get closed.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for the advice, but I am actually not-so-new to other SE communities, so I tried to keep the question as objective as possible. Now keep in mind that I am not looking for "don't go to club X", but "if you go to district X, be careful, since it has a not-so-good fame".
One question per post does not imply that what you mean. In that case I should have asked "how can I be safe in BKK" (which indeed is too broad), but I actually restricted the thing to be more specific. Thanks anyway for the feedback and feel free to edit if you think it helps the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What constitutes 'trustworthy' or 'safe' very much depends on your own standards. I would say that Bangkok is quite safe. It's exceptional for tourists to be the targets of violent crime. But, tourists are an obvious target nonetheless, probably more so through scams than crime. [Here](http://travelscams.org/asia/common-tourist-scams-thailand/)'s just one of many articles on the web that list Thai scams you should be aware of.

As a rule of thumb, you are more likely to be targeted in areas with more tourists. You are more likely to be targeted when it's quiet. You are more likely to be targeted, the more intoxicated you are. The more a tourist you look (that has a bit to do with your race, but more so with how you behave), the more likely you'll be targeted.

In my mind, no nightclub (anywhere) is absolutely trustworthy. The more expensive ones will probably try to scam you less, but their scam is the price you're paying, to begin with.

Comment: Well I think it's common sense not leaving your backpack away from your eyes, not yelling "hey I have a lot of cash" in a crowd and not being in streets that you don't know, with no company, intoxicated, with a laptop in your hand. So let's assume that security depends *more or less* from one's standards. 
What I meant is if there are any districts not to go in the night to avoid getting robbed (which by the way I have no clue whether is a violent crime) and so on.
Would you please care to elaborate a bit on the nightclubs (I'm not necessarily talking about go-go bars and so on...)

Comment: Not sure what elaboration you need on nightclubs, but there's also this: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53962/where-can-i-find-go-go-bars-in-bangkok

Comment: If you get pick-pocketed, it's not a violent crime. Getting robbed (under threat of violence) is. However, if it would be that easy to say which districts to not go to at night, they would quickly become violence-free (and people-free).

Comment: lol I saw that question too, but as I said, I'm not looking for places with "negotiable virtue women". Something like bars, discos, places where you get to see thai-boxe encounters...

Comment: As a obvious tourist, you will always be an easier target. As a tourist in popular tourist destinations, you will run a higher risk of being targeted. Most crime in Thailand is not violent, so be diligent. And, particularly when going out at night, carry few valuables. It also helps if you can give the impression that you will smash to pulp a person trying to steal from you.